# The Great Attractor

Tags: cosmology

Somewhere in the Universe (I forget where) there is a mysterious object dubbed by astronomers [The Great Attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Attractor), which is drawing a gigantic cluster of galaxies towards it. Have astronomers figured out what this object is,& is its presence taken into account when assessing the mass of the universe? Could there be more like it?

Comment: "*The Great Attractor [...] is drawing a gigantic cluster of galaxies towards it.*" - Not according to Wiki: "*These galaxies are all redshifted, in accordance with the Hubble Flow, indicating that they are receding relative to us and to each other*" - This means they are flying away from the Great Attractor (just slower).

Comment: Maybe,but I don't know much about it,which is why I asked the question. I first saw it mentioned a few years ago,so it is possible that a lot more is known about it now.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w4OTD4L0GQ&t=100s , 
It remains to be demonstrated that the universe is rotating....

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2023/04/the-universe-sucks-the-mysterious-great-attractor-thats-pulling-us-in/) (which I thoroughly recommend reading in full) explains it quite well to a lay audience like me:

> [...] it’s best not to think of the Great Attractor as a thing but as a place. It’s a locus, a focal point of gravitational attraction. It’s the bottom of the well, so to speak, of our local gravitational environment.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w4OTD4L0GQ&t=100s , 
It remains to be demonstrated that the universe is rotating....